# Twitter Search API is returning weird characters - is it me or is it them?

Tags: twitter, character-encoding, jsonp

We are building an app that accesses the Twitter search over JSONP.

It mostly works fine, but occasionally the request returns a JSONP callback that consists of weird unparseable characters.

Here is an example: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?result_type=recent&rpp=100&geocode=51.4375857,-0.1658648,1km&page=5&callback=jsonp1272532482854

(If you change page=5 to a value less than 5 in the URL it works fine)

So

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Edit: This is no longer a problem, so I guess this was just a bug that got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that should be fixed now. https://groups.google.com/d/topic/twitter-development-talk/X7J_e9bOY-o/discussion